# how to recast and print variables in lldb

Tags: lldb, macos-high-sierra

I have a pointer to a string

```
void *s = "now is the time for all"
```

and I wish to print it as an integer of 32-bit size:

```
gdb) p /x *((int *)s)
```

What is the equivalence in `lldb` parlance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly that, except you can't put a space between the `p` and the `/x`.

lldb's command syntax is not the same as lldb's (for more details see:

http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html

) but `p` (among others) was added (as an alias to the lldb `expr` command) for people more familiar with gdb's commands.  However, to get the `/x` part working through lldb's command parser it has to be directly postpended to the actual command name so it isn't confused with arguments and options.  So:

```
(lldb) p/x *((int *) text_to_use)
(int) $1 = 0x8f06c8c0
```

There's also a cheat sheet for lldb <-> gdb commands here:

http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html

which you might find handy.

Comment: Why in the world does lldb reinstitue strong typing?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: After working on gdb for over 10 years, I was constantly amazed by how small the subset of gdb commands people actually knew existed was.  I think part of the reason is the command structure of gdb is flat and fairly ad hoc, which made it hard to explore.  So in lldb we ordered the commands in a logical, easy to explore fashion.  Then we added several powerful alias facilities so that common commands could be typed quickly.  There's a built-in set listed at the end of the 'help' command.  And you can add your own if there are commands you use more frequently.

Comment: Note also, lldb does shortest unique matching so you generally have to only type one or two characters of the command name.